# SwipeMenuListView new Row added is showing First time data

Tags: android, listview

I've read many of the previous posts on this topic, but i'm not getting it right.

I have an adapter which has a private values of the items in the list.
When i update the values(add a new items), i watch the value in debugger and the "getView" func and see that the value is correct.

**BUT the actual rowView i see is just the first item in the list.**

I have no clue what may cause this.

This listview is on the same activity while i **show** a different layout and hide the listview to add a new item.

Can there be a connection while the listview visibility is "GONE"?
When i remove items from it it updates listview fine(that is done when listview is visible).

```
private void updateAdapter() {
    this.values.clear();
    this.values.addAll(staticlistIndifferentclass);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**~~~~UPDATE~~~~**
Ok,
So i discovered the cause of the problem, though i'm not sure why it is.
The code was fine the way it was **with regular Listview** but the bug is on:

com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView

Comment: Can you share the piece of code of `adapter` class?? and also where that notifydatasetchanged has been used

Comment: Can u post how u r initializing the adapter?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I used a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Use new `Adapter` object like this :

```
listView.setAdapter(new yourCustomAdapter());
```

When you delete all dataSet items ,it is better to bind new `Adapter` object .

Comment: Creating new adapter on every change to the list is not a correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [ListView.invalidateViews](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29)

This should cause views rebuilding